# How can I set a return URL for an edit link in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, urlhacking, outputlink

I have a visualforce page displaying a list of Event objects that need users to update. I have an 'Update link' that takes them to the edit screen for the Event, but upon Save, it brings up the list page. I want to take them to their home page, where this list VF page is nested.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="fale" standardController="User" extensions="UsersEventsExt2">

  <apex:pageBlock title="Meetings to Update">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Events}" var="c">

      <apex:column headerValue="Click to Update"><apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Event.Edit,c.id)}" target="_blank">Update Meeting</apex:outputLink></apex:column>

       <apex:column headerValue="Subject"><apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Event.View,c.id)}" target="_blank">{!c.subject}</apex:outputLink></apex:column>

       <
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When saving a new record, you can use the `saveURL` parameter:

```
{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.NewContact, c.id, ['saveURL'='/home/home.jsp'])}
```

When editing an existing record, you can use the `retURL` parameter:

```
{!URLFOR($Action.Event.Edit, c.id, ['retURL'='/home/home.jsp'])}
```