# returnUrl commandButton

Tags: apex, visualforce

I would like to set a return URL after pressing the save commandButton on a new record page. How can I do this?

Code:

```
  <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}" styleClass="btn btn-default" rerender="error,styledError,unstyledError"/>
```

**EDIT:** I would like it redirect to my own custom detail page, which means I must also pass the ID of the record as a paramater

Comment: use PageReference

Comment: Hi Imran. Do you mean that you have a VF page with the standard controller, and after you press "Save" (which calls the standardcontroller Save method) you want to return to your own URL?

How do you get to the VF page in the first place? Is it from a button or link or something?

Comment: @Dominic Yes thats exactly what I want. The user will get inital visualforce form via a link from my force.com site.

Comment: The answer given by @JennyB is good then. You set `&saveURL=/apex/mynextpage` on the link that leads to your vf page. Then when the user presses "Save" they go to `/apex/mynextpage`

Comment: @Dominic I have tried adding this to initial new record page url, but when pressing save I am still redirected to the normal detail page for the record.

Comment: what does you modified link look like?

Comment: @Dominic so I tried adding the paramter to the loaded url like this: `mysite.force.com/newOrder?saveURL=/OrderDetail`. I also tried changing the button url like so: `<apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Service_Order__c.Save, so.id, ['retURL'='/home/home.jsp'])}"/>`. Please look at my updated post, I added an additional requirement I forgot to mention.

Comment: please check the documentation that @Jenny B links below. You need the 'saveURL' parameter. The id of the newly created record will be automatically added in to the URL, I think as "newId".

Comment: @Dominic am adding the parameter in the wrong place? I have placed a SaveURL parameter in the initial URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the button/link that is calling the edit page, you can set the saveURL/retURL parameter to control where the page returns to after the "Save" button is clicked. If the page is being called from the standard page, then you could create a custom button and set the parameter in the URL that way. Examples shown [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27533/how-can-i-set-a-return-url-for-an-edit-link-in-visualforce).

Answer (score 0):

```
public PageReference save() {
    // Add the account to the database. 
    insert account;
    // Send the user to the detail page for the new account.
   // You can set your return url here
    PageReference acctPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(account).view();
    acctPage.setRedirect(true);
    return acctPage;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using a controller extension?

Comment: see this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3907/redirecting-back-to-original-page-using-visualforce if it can help you

Comment: How could I forward this to my own custom visualforce page and also pass the ID of the new record as a URL parameter?